# "Wait-free" data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I've been led to believe that the GHC implementation of `TVar`s is [lock-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom), but not [wait-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Wait-freedom). Are there any implementations that are wait-free (e.g. a package on Hackage)?

Comment: From the Wikipedia page, it seems that wait-freedom is a property of an algorithm, not a data structure.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps that's the incorrect usage of the term. What I mean is by wrapping all of your data in `TVar`s makes any algorithm lock-free. I'd like to know if there was a datatype that makes any algoritm wait-free.

Answer (score 3):

Wait-freedom is a term from distributed computing. An algorithm is *wait-free* if a thread (or distributed node) is able to terminate correctly even if all input from other threads is delayed/lost at any time.

If you care about consistency, then you cannot guarantee wait-freedom (assuming that you always want to terminate correctly, i.e. guarantee availability). This follows from the **CAP theorem** [1], since wait-freedom essentially implies partition-tolerance.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

Comment: Sounds like a mixup of terms to me. Typically, "wait-free" simply means that all threads make forward progress. For example (in C++, sorry), the function `inc` is wait-free `std::atomic<int> i; void inc(){ i++; }` because each thread that enters never stops progressing. Contrast that with a lock-free algorithm (like a lock-free stack), which requires no locks and is atomic, but only progresses one thread at a time (though because of its high-granularity, is quicker in high-load situations).

Comment: @GManNickG: If you just consider `inc()` as a zero-time atomic operation then I agree, `inc()` will be wait-free. 

However, if you look at how the atomicity of `inc()` is actually implemented it must either entail some locking or some form of "retrying" to guarantee consistency, since there's a chance that 2 threads read the same value simultaneously before one of them writes. So if you look at it at this level, `inc()` isn't wait-free, because one of the threads needs to reread the value before going forward.

Comment: Fair enough, I made some assumptions without specifying. But there is hardware-level atomicity, which at the program-level is lock-free and wait-free.

Comment: @GManNickG: Right, with hardware support it's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Your question "Are there any implementations that are wait-free?" is a bit incomplete.  STM (and thus `TVar`) is rather complex and has support built into the compiler - you can't build it properly with Haskell primitives.

If you're looking for any data container that allows mutation and can be non-blocking then you want `IORef`s or `MVar`s (but those can block if no value is available).

Comment: You _can_ implement STM yourself. It doesn't need to be hard-wired into the compiler. (Though it's probably more efficient that way.) See issue #15 of The Monad Reader for source code.

Comment: `IORef`s can't be empty and won't block, as I understand it.

Comment: @Math Haskell has no lock free / CAS primitives for a true ATM afaik, so I'll gladly see MR when I have time.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Ahh, so Andrew simulated STM behavior using a locking scheme.  I would argue this is not STM any more than a well-engineered mechanical duck is a duck - they are fundamentally different in their underlying behavior in ways that matter to users.  It was a fun read though, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: STM guarantees that your transactions are atomic and isolated. There are many possible ways to implement that. Note, also, that the STM implementation in the paper only briefly locks stuff during the commit phase. During the main transaction, nothing is locked. This is exactly the same behaviour as GHC's native implementation, which has to prevent changes while it does its "validate" step. GHC probably does it more efficiently, of course...

Comment: What? GHC doesn't use MCAS?  Arrrggghhh, my world is being inverted!